# C# WebBrowser button addtocart Click it , then go to the next another page and click submit

Tags: c#, winforms, getelementbyid

i used this to click in the first page

```
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("vwd-add-to-cart").InvokeMember("click");
```

and i want to click in submit button in the next page 
after the previous completely loaded.

```
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shipping-first-name").SetAttribute("value", "john");
```

after clicking in addtocart button and the page loaded i want to put this in first name

how I  will know that I am in the next page after clicked on the first page and start put code in the next page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKbWL.gif)??
 here you can see gif pic to understand 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKbWL.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You should register an event DocumentCompleted

[WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webDocument);



private void webDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // this will raise after your page loaded.
}
```